# How to check if nested array does not contain a certain array?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

This code checks the background of a certain number of cells.

```
var array = sheet.getRange(1, 1, 20, 1).getBackgrounds();
```

If I log this array in the Google Apps Script console, it returns the following array:

```
[[#cccccc], [#ffffff], [#ffffff], [#ffffff], [#ffffff], [#cccccc], [#ffffff], [#ffffff], [#ffffff], [#ffffff], [#f3f3f3], [#ffffff], [#ffffff], [#ffffff], [#ffffff], [#ffffff], [#cccccc], [#cccccc], [#ffffff], [#ffffff]]
```

I want to check if this array **does not** contain a certain color code: `#377a47`.

I tried to use `includes` for this, however this does not work as the value is an array and not a string.

```
console.log(!array.includes("#377a47")); // returns true
```

This should return true, as the array does not contain this #377a47 color code. And it does return true, however it also returns true if I try the following color code that **is** present in the array:

```
console.log(!array.includes("#cccccc")); // returns true
```

So apparently this is not the right way to check if the array does not contain `#377a47`. I suspected it had something to do with the fact it is a nested array, but am not sure how to correctly write the code to check this.

***My Question:** How to correctly check if the array does not contain the color code `#377a47`?*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Arrays in JavaScript are compared by reference so even approach:

```js
array.includes(["#377a47"]) //returns false
```

won't work

You can try [flattening an array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat) and compare primitive values like this:

```
console.log(![[1], [2], [3]].flat().includes(1)); //returns false
```